# Getting oracle client installed on a VM to communicate with Oracle 12G on a different VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, oracle-11g, oracle-linux

Can anyone help me figure this one out? I can sucessfully connect to the VM Oracle Server with sqlplus on my host OS but on VM2 where i have my sqlplus installed i cant seem to connect giving Localhost and port as address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should interconnect your virtual machines.
Then, you can set the IP of the VM server into the VM client. SQLPlus is using a file named "tnsnames.ora" where you can add your resolving IP of the VM Oracle Server
You can check this documentation to know more about it : [Identifying and Accessing the Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/concepts.htm)